# Xamarin.Android Firebase.Messaging - D/FirebaseInstanceId(13164): background sync failed: INVALID_SENDER

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am adding push notifications to a Xamarin app in development.
After following guides I've done everything that should allow it to work.

- google-services.json downloaded from firebase, added to project and build action set to GoogleServicesJson
- play services is available as confirmed in a check
- receiver node added to AndroidManifest.xml
- FirebaseIIDService implemented
- Notification channel is created

mainfest receiver code:

```
<application android:label="RMS Metro Calendar">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

FirebaseIID code (I'm not implementing registration management on the server side):

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

The app builds and deploys fine, I can sucessfully log out that Play services is available and in logging I get: FirebaseApp initialization successful

However it does not generate a Firebase instance and no Instance.Token is ever received. All I get is the following logging message:

> 09-19 13:48:31.576 D/FirebaseInstanceId(18578): background sync
>   failed: INVALID_SENDER, retry in 10s

from which is continues to retry in ever growing time scales.

I'm sure there must be something I've configured incorrectly somewhere with regards to the receiver/IID service implementation, but for the life of me cannot figure it out.

Has anyone else ever come across this? Is there a way I can test the FCM service for my configuration to get back more information on why it is failing?

Thank you!

Comment: That error is typically a mismatch in your google-services.json to your Firebase console setup, make sure that your app's package name / sha hash matches.

Comment: But how if I've downloaded the google-services.json directly from Firebase when creating the project?

Comment: Because you have to add your app's signing sha to Firebase

Comment: Surely this would be true if the app was being distributed, but I'm debugging it locally? I have not made it available on the play store.
I have done other projects before like this and never needed to use the SHA key for Firebase.

Comment: Same holds true for debugging, a pre-approved client has to be used (Play Store distribution is not a requirement to use Firebase as there are apps not using Play Store but other Android Stores (which are actually prevalent in many parts of the world) and those apps are not "validating" themselves to Google/Play but to Firebase.) and of course ad-hoc distribution works with Firebase...

Comment: Ok. Could you please provide an answer with steps for doing this and if it works I'll accept it for you?

Comment: Xamarin has a doc to obtain your app's MD5/SHA1 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=vswin

Comment: So I've followed the guide in your link, found the SHA1 for my debug machine and added this as a finger print to my Firebase Project. I've also uninstalled the app from my simulator and reinstalled/run it. No change, it is still throwing me the very same message.